# Ubuntu 19.10 wont boot after grub menu ubuntu selection

Tags: boot, 19.10, grub-efi

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 19.10(UEFI).

A) I can’t boot to Ubuntu after grub selection. I can't enter Ubuntu to have bash to disable it. Are there any ideas?

B) Also, since Ubuntu is the only OS on my PC, why do I need GRUB?

Comment: 1) Are Secure Boot and Fast Boot disabled? 2) IS the BIOS set for Legacy or UEFI? 3) Is the BIOS drive type set to Legacy, AHCI, or RAID? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: _B) Why do I need GRUB?_ Technically, you don't as per https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/1sxcie/if_linux_is_only_distro_on_hdd_do_you_need_grub/ and  https://www.quora.com/When-and-why-do-we-need-grub-bootloader-in-ubuntu-linux but you must have _some_ kind of bootloader, and GRUB2 is  a tool which make solving a lot of boot problems easier as well as performing the boot load process.

Answer (score 0):

Let me recommend the rEFInd boot manager.  You can install it and it will find the various operating systems and let you boot them.  At least for me, on multiple machines, this "just works."

rEFInd page here: https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/

Installation instructions here: https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html

Comment: It would be kind to write the important steps in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a fresh install, it wouldn't hurt to do a fresh install again, would it? Anyway, if that doesn't work or isn't an option, you can try [Rescatux](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/).